# Converting Microsoft EWS StreamingNotification Example to a service

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I've been working to try and convert Microsoft's EWS Streaming Notification Example to a service
( MS source http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27154).

I tested it as a console app. I then used a generic service template and got it to the point it would compile, install, and start. It stops after about 10 seconds with the ubiquitous "the  service on local computer started and then stopped."

So I went back in and upgraded to C# 2013 express and used NLog to put a bunch of log trace commands to so I could see where it was when it exited.

The last place I can find it is in the example code, SynchronizationChanges function,

```
public static void SynchronizeChanges(FolderId folderId)
{
   logger.Trace("Entering SynchronizeChanges");
   bool moreChangesAvailable;
   do
   {
      logger.Trace("Synchronizing changes...");
      //Console.WriteLine("Synchronizing changes...");
      // Get all changes since the last call. The synchronization cookie is stored in the
      // _SynchronizationState field.
      // Only the the ids are requested. Additional properties should be fetched via GetItem 
      //calls. 
      logger.Trace("Getting changes into var changes.");

      var changes = _ExchangeService.SyncFolderItems(folderId, PropertySet.IdOnly, null, 512,
                                                      SyncFolderItemsScope.NormalItems, 
                                                      _SynchronizationState);

      // Update the synchronization cookie
      logger.Trace("Updating _SynchronizationState");
```

the log file shows the trace message ""Getting changes into var changes." but not the "Updating _SynchronizationState" message.

so it never gets past var changes = _ExchangeService.SyncFolderItems

I cannot for the life figure out why its just exiting. There are many examples of EWS streaming notifications. I have 3 that compile and run just fine but nobody as far as I can tell has posted an example of it done as a service.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see the "Updating..." message it's likely the sync threw an exception.  Wrap it in a try/catch.

OK, so now that I see the error, this looks like your garden-variety permissions problem.  When you ran this as a console app, you likely presented the default credentials to Exchange, which were for your login ID.  For a Windows service, if you're running the service with one of the built-in accounts (e.g. Local System), your default credentials will not have access to Exchange.

To rectify, either (1) run the service under the account you did the console app with, or (2) add those credentials to the Exchange Service object.

Comment: 2014-03-15 12:24:20.0018|TRACE|MailAlert.Service1|Getting changes into var changes.
2014-03-15 12:24:21.4549|TRACE|MailAlert.Service1|Error: Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.